# Why is my answer wrong? (Inverse Functions)

Tags: trigonometry

> Find the inverse function of $g(x)=-4x+1$.

So I replace $g(x)$ with $y$, then solve for $x$:

$$ 4x=1-y\\ x = \frac{1-y}4\\ y = \frac{1-x}4$$ The answer was $g(x)^{-1} =(-1/4)x + 1/4$.

Problem #12: http://www.kutasoftware.com/FreeWorksheets/Alg2Worksheets/Function%20Inverses.pdf

Comment: $$
1-x/4\neq (1-x)/4.
$$
You forgot to divide everything by 4, as far as I can tell from your notation.

Comment: That was a typo. It was suppose to be (1-x)/4.

Comment: Your method and answer are essentially correct. I would skip the switcheroo between $x$ and $y$, though. If $y=g(x)$, then you should write the inverse function as $x=g^{-1}(y)$. Note also you should correct the placement of the "$-1$"--it should be written as $g^{-1}(y)$, not $g(y)^{-1}$. The latter signifies $\frac{1}{g(y)}$. Otherwise good!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$g(x)=-4x+1\\
\mbox{Let $g(x)=y$. Then, }-4x=y-1\\
x=(y-1)/(-4)\\
x=\dfrac{1-y}{4}\\
\boxed{g^{-1}(x)=\dfrac{1-x}{4}}$$
Or, simplifying,
$$g^{-1}(x)=\dfrac{1-x}{4}\\
g^{-1}(x)=\dfrac{1}{4}-\dfrac{x}{4}=\dfrac{1}{4}-\dfrac{1}{4}x\\
\boxed{g^{-1}(x)=-\dfrac{1}{4}x+\dfrac{1}{4}}$$

Comment: That's what I got for the answer, but this worksheet says otherwise.It's problem # 12. http://www.kutasoftware.com/FreeWorksheets/Alg2Worksheets/Function%20Inverses.pdf

Comment: @igknighton See my edited answer.

Comment: @igknighton Your answer's not wrong - it's a simplified form of the answer given at the link.